# Kendo grid converting datetime to greenwich time

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid, datetime-conversion

I have a kendo grid with a datetime column.  The format of the column is to show time only.

```
 columns.Bound(p => p.Brief).Format("{0:HH:mm}").EditorTemplateName("BriefTimePicker").Width(100);
```

the data that is being loaded into the column is coming in from the database with a time value of 6:00 but when it gets displayed in the grid it is 1:00.  Is there some way to keep it from converting to greenwich time?

Answer (score 0):

try this

columns.Bound(c => c.Brief).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(Brief,'d') #")..EditorTemplateName("BriefTimePicker").Width(100);

Date Formating available on this link.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/globalization/dateformatting

regards

Shaz